How do I get 5*2=10 instead that =10.0?
Sorry for the very basic question.
Within a tixz context, I need to multiply two integers and get an integer (no decimal  part).
I don't see how.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations, decorations.text} 
\newcommand\neww{} % just for safety
\def\neww[#1,#2]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{#1} % radius
\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{#2} % number of parts
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}{
\draw [densely dotted, fill=red!40] (0,0) -- +(360/\n*\i:\r) arc (360/\n*\i:360/\n*(\i-1):\r) node [pos=.5, sloped, above] {\n}  ;
}
}
   \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
    \neww[5, multiply(5,2)] <<< prints 10.0
\end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
    \neww[5, 5*2]  <<< prints 10.0
\end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex']
    \neww[5, 10]   <<< prints 10
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



int() returns an integer.

\pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{int(#2)} 

will return an integer.
Note that your definition of \neww is rather confusing because it requires an argument in square brackets, which breaks standard LaTeX syntax. You should also be careful. As it stands, the second argument you are passing to the code begins with a space. This gets lost when it is processed by pgfmath, but it might matter in other cases.
To use curly brackets/braces for the required argument, you want two functions rather than one. For example,
\def\newwaux#1,#2\nil{%
  x#1x#2x%
}
\newcommand\neww[1]{%
  \expandafter\newwaux#1\nil
}

This will also demonstrate the issue with the space:
 \neww{5,10} \neww{5, 10}


Yes, of course, shame on me!, I should have remembered. Thanks. On the other issue, what instead of []? Also, which space?

@mario No shame ;). \neww[5, 10] is different from \neww[5,10]. The first passes 5 and  10, whereas the second passes 5 and 10. That doesn't matter here, but it would in other cases. If it is a mandatory argument, use curly brackets. Or use something obviously non-standard. For the former, you'd need two definitions and pass the argument between them. See above.

@mario Or you can do fancy things with the new expl3 programming layer or some other tool which would let you split the list. You could also do this using pgfkeys which provides a n args handler which takes delimited arguments.

Actually, I was too fancy. A more usual \newcommand{\neww}[2]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{#1}, \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{#2}, bla bla}, works fine, doesn't it? (spaces are a typo)

@mario Oh, certainly. I thought you used \def because you wanted to use the specific syntax with a comma rather than saying \neww{5}{10} or whatever. But the more obvious and straightforward solution is \newcommand with 2 arguments, indeed.
